# Log out error keeps appearing

Tags: support, bug

Today I wanted to log out from EE from the mobile site but I can't.Instead,I keep getting an error message which says:"We apologize for any inconvenience,but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site".How can this situation be fixed?
**EDIT:** I logged out of another site and it automatically logged me out of EE,too.However,this only works if I change the settings of the browser to "desktop version".The mobile version won't.The error persists and won't let me log off directly.What's going on??

Comment: You can check out any time you like, but you can never leave.

Comment: I've done this before,I logged out from the mobile site directly out of EE.Now there is some error which keeps me from suceeding in doing that.